# AJAX not posting data to PHP in IE only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

So I have an AJAX call that I'm using to POST 1 variable to a PHP script I have on a separate server. The PHP takes this variable and returns data based off of what the variable is. This works on all browsers except IE9 and below. IE9 returns data but it's an error saying the variable is missing which to me shows that it isn't sending the data. Below I have the AJAX call I'm making:

```
(function (jQ) {

var inviteID = '00000000000';

jQ.ajax({
    url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: { classID: inviteID },
    error: function (data, status, error) {
        jQ('.statusField').append('Failure: ' + data + status + error);
    },
    success: function (data, status, error) {
        jQ('.statusField').append('Success: ' + data);
    }
 }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

And below I have the PHP script that's being used:

```
<?php
//first POST to grab token
function runPost($classID) {

$postdata = array(
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password'
);
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postdata));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'example');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

list($message, $time, $token, $userID) = split(',', $result);
list($one, $two, $three, $four, $five) = split('\"', $token);
$four = json_encode($four);
$four = str_replace('"','',$four);


$secondaryPostData = array(
    'token' => $four,
    'data' => array( 'invitationID' => $classID
));

//open connection
$chu = curl_init();

//set the url, POST data
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/classID");
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($secondaryPostData));
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'example');
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post

$secondResult = curl_exec($chu);

//close connection
curl_close($chu);
return json_encode($secondResult);
}
//Grab classID from javascript
echo runPost(trim($_POST['classID']));
?>
```

Again, this works fine in everything except IE. I've tried several different methods but everything gives me the same error. The network console in IE shows that the Request body does have the classID in it, but I'm guessing it's just not sending the data to the PHP script. I don't know if I'm missing something that IE needs to send this to the PHP script but any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: try with : data: { 'classID': inviteID },

Comment: Check the IE network console for the response it is getting back from the php script.

Comment: Adding the quotes around classID didn't work. This is what I get back from the script: Success: {"error":"missing required data [invitationID]","code":400}

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried using this ?**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("demo_test.php",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

works for me in chrome and IE.

`$.post()` is a short hand method for `$.ajax();`
It does every thing you could do in `$.ajax();` when I started having this problem I never used `$.ajax();` unless I had to send FormData an entire object off all the field inputs in a form

Comment: I have tried to use .post and I get the same response. The script is giving me the correct response for the error it's getting, but it's getting the error because IE won't POST the actual data to the script.